# Sql Matching multiple criteria, Group users by worst skills

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, laravel

**Hi everyone.**

I need to **group participants by their 5 worst skills in order to create classrooms**.

I also need to be aware that they live in different parts of the world (Americas, Europe and Asia).

I need to mix and match them where timezones are not too distant from each other (Americas with some of Europe and Asia with rest of Europe).

**I have 160 participants** and I would need to create **12 classrooms**.

Participants table:

```
id name country_id
------------------
1 | name  | 8 |
2 | name2 | 3 |
3 | name  | 4 |
4 | name2 | 8 |
and so on....
```

Country table:

```
id name 
------------------
1 | Japan      | 
2 | USA        | 
3 | Australia  | 
4 | UK         | 
and so on....
```

Skills

```
id name
------------------
1 | skill1      | 
2 | skill2      | 
3 | skill3      | 
4 | skill4      | 
and so on....
```

participant_skill table:

```
participant_id skill_id
------------------
1 | 2      | 
1 | 4      | 
1 | 3      | 
1 | 5      | 
1 | 9      | 
2 | 1      | 
2 | 4      | 
2 | 3      | 
2 | 6      | 
2 | 9      | 
3 | 2      | 
3 | 7      | 
3 | 8      | 
3 | 5      | 
3 | 9      | 
and so on....
```

Ideally the result would get me something like this:

```
group_id participant_id country_id
----------------------------------
1 | 5  | 1  |
1 | 63 | 4  |
1 | 71 | 5  |
1 | 95 | 4  |
1 | 18 | 5  |
1 | 83 | 8  |
1 | 44 | 1  |
1 | 4  | 8  |
1 | 73 | 5  |
1 | 36 | 12 |
1 | 53 | 12 |
1 | 12 | 8  |
1 | 21 | 5  |
1 | 10 | 4  |
2 | 34 | 13 |
2 | 22 | 13 |
2 | 2  | 15 |
and so on...
```

Any idea how to get this to work?

Thank you very much and happy coding ^^

E

****UPDATE**
I managed to select the 5 worst skills by running this SQL query:

```
select p.id, p.name, s.id from `participants` p
left join `regions` r on p.`region_id` = r.`id`
left join `participant_skill` ps on p.`id` = ps.`participant_id`
left join skills s on ps.`skill_id` = s.`id`
where ps.`rank` > 11
```

**Now I don't know how to match participants together based on their worst Skills and Region.**

Here is a dump of the tables.
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rqtP5HnoyiwSKiy9Jmx8KV/1

I hope that helps

;)

Comment: I just don't know how to do this by my self... So there isn't any code to test or reproduce yet :)

Comment: How do you know what skills are _the worst_?

Comment: they fill in a questionnaire. I diggest and rank them with php then store them in the pivot table.

Comment: Yes but there's no column to define a rank for them in your question? Presumable there's a field like `participant_skill.rank`?

Comment: and where does your `group_id` come from?

Comment: Sorry my bad, I haven't got a participant_skill.rank but just the participant_skill table which are their worst 5 skills. the group_id would live in the final table and isn't created yet...

Comment: Are all classes the same size? Do the classes all have to be the same set of skills? How will you decide which countries can match? Maybe add a time zone column and allow `-1 hour < x < +1 hour`

Comment: The class should be 15 participants max. They don't have to be the same size as long as I have 12 of them. I can match people from Europe with both Americas and Asia but I can't match Americas with Asia is the only constraint :)

Comment: For the skills I would love for the participants to match most of their worst skills. Not all :)

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query -  I'm not pretending that the solution to this np-complete problem is straightforward, but at least the data set is fairly small.

Comment: Hi Guys I have updated the question with a dump and the query I am currently running. Let me know if you need anything else. E

Comment: You said you want to group on the worst `5` skills... However, out of your entire data set as far as I can tell there's a grand total of about `2` participants with matching skills? So how do you want to filter that?

Comment: Hi Steven, I want to distribute people in classroom by the most matching 5 worst skills, not an exact match. I just want to create classrooms where most participants will learn across the same set of skills. Does that make more sense?